# Error: Request Entity Too Large: head - Any Suggestions?

Tags: custom-object, error, limits, validation-rule

I am creating my Data Model - Created one Custom Object with around 400 fields and 15-20 Validation Rules on it.

Now, When I am trying to add more Validation Rules - It is giving me following error on the complete blank White Screen with following error message in the corner---

> Error: Request Entity Too Large: head

Since we have 500 Max limit for fields and 100 for validation rules ->

[image]

Why am I facing this error / issue ?

What could be the possible things I am missing or doing in wrong way?

Any Suggestions !!

Comment: I have seen this with field sets as well. When the error is displayed it (for me) usually resolves itself when I simply refresh the page.

Comment: @Eric - I was facing this issue the whole day. Somehow I am back on Track today, But I am now going with JS Validations to avoid future issues of limit n all. But I need to know why we are going through such situation ??

Comment: Did you check was there perfomace degradation on your instance? you can check it at http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/instances